# Error Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

Tags: react-native, firebase-storage

I got an error when I installed firebase storage in the react-native project
when I installed the firebase app & firebase storage in my project, in the console I got ***found 3 low vulnerabilities*** then after running **npm audit fix** I got error  **Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED**
after this, I'm also getting
***error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.***

Comment: are you using rnFirebase? You are on windows or mac

Comment: i am using firebase in my project and using windows